# C# WPF Chart X Axis

Tags: c#

I have a chart created in WPF.
I want to hide the coordinates on the x-axis because they overlap. How can I do this?

```html
<DVC:Chart Name="mcChart"
                   Background="DarkGray" Margin="10,5,10,10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
            <DVC:Chart.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </DVC:Chart.RenderTransform>
            <DVC:Chart.Series>
                <DVC:LineSeries Title="Gesture Middle"
                               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                               DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
                </DVC:LineSeries>

            </DVC:Chart.Series>
        </DVC:Chart>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m0pM.png)

Comment: Please add the code used to create the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the chart inside the `LineSeries` to display the labels on an interval:

```
<DVC:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="Something" Interval="10"/>
</DVC:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
```

Change the `Interval` value to get larger and smaller intervals.

Comment: I have like 500 values , I don’t think this solution will help me . Do you know another way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you try setting the `Interval="100"` or some high number? You would only display 5 labels then and they wouldn't overlap.